# Comparing performance of Mongodb database of various size

Tags: mongodb, performance, performance-testing, database-performance

I've read a recommendation that the size of MongoDB database should be no more than twice the the RAM on the server. I tried to test this recommendation with using https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB, but so far it looks that the performance penalty I see is ONLY during the load to the database (writes) and not on read actions.

I have 192GB RAM on my server, so I've compared two databases:

- "Normal size" loaded with 300,000,000 objects which takes 350GB on disk.
- "Big size"   loaded with 1200,000,000 objects which takes 1.4TB on the disk.

db.stats reports that the index size of the "normal size" db is 20GB and for the large DB it's 60GB.

It took 2300 seconds to load the small database. 
Due to the limited memory, I expected that it will take more than 4 times to load the "big size" database. It actually took 30310 seconds which is 13 times in comparison to the time to load the "normal size" database.

I than tested few - as defined by YCSB benchmark:

In all the workload I tested and for veraity number of client threads, the throughput reading of the large database was +/- 10% of the normal size database.

My main questions:

- Is there something wrong with the approach I took for this test?
- What is actually the practical size for database according to the RAM size on the server?
- Are there some tuning I should do so I get better throughput while loading data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I figured that my test is probably not good-enough. 
That's because YCSB uses by default zipfian distribution. 
It means that my dataset in RAM includes the data for most queries in the test.

It seems that a better test would be with 'uniform' distribution instead of zipfian.